# Why Gitlab use with jenkins?

Tags: gitlab

While I'm searching for CI/CD, there are many post about setting gitlab jenkins pipeline.

As far as I know jenkins is CI/CD tool and Gitlab has CI/CD feature too.

why use both two CI/CD tools at same time, instead of using gitlab only?

I tried to find the reason on google.

but i can't found..